# Capture variable string in a regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, string-literals

In C#, I'm attempting to use the following capture pattern with a variable - I wonder if I'm going about this wrong. info_name is a string variable I pass to the method.

```
    Regex g = new Regex(@"""" + info_name + """>.+</span>");
    // capture "info">Capture pattern</span>
```

But it gives me an error, ')' expected about halfway through. This gives no error:

```
    Regex g = new Regex(@"""" + info_name +">.+</span>");
                                         //^ 1 quote, not 3
```

I can't use this as a solution, I need to capture the " just before the close of the tag.

Comment: But be wary of what you pass in in info_name - if it happens to contain any special Regex characters, it may mess up your Regex.

Comment: @Nikki: Good point. That can be handled using [`Regex.Escape`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.escape.aspx) if necessary. I didn't add that to my own answer because it's possible that `info_name` has already been pre-processed or suitably sanitised.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using two string literals there, so you need to apply the `@` both times:

```
Regex g = new Regex(@"""" + info_name + @""">.+</span>");

// or alternatively
Regex g = new Regex("\"" + info_name + "\">.+</span>");
```

Comment: Thanks! For some reason escaping a quote " with \" doesn't work, it stops the expression. I have to use "" to escape it. Your first answer seemed to work! Thanks a bunch! Also, I read why parsing HTML with Regex is an unholy sin like the work of satan, so I might try another way to do this.

Comment: Or use `new Regex("\"" + info_name + "\">.+</span>")`. @ is often used in Regex strings, because Regexes often contain backslash characters, and you have to escape each one with another backslash in regular strings (without the @).

Comment: Ah, that's why the \ was cancelling it out. I have a lot to learn. =\