# Dynamic Regex replaces single backslash with double backslash in C#

Tags: c#, regex, replace

In my code I am saving the Regular Expression for validating the UK Mobile number i.e. "^(+44\s?7\d{3}|(?07\d{3})?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$" in to the Sql server database.

On retrieving the expression to validate the mobile number the "\" will be replaced with the "\", this gives a serious issue as on checking it says the mobile number is invalid even though its valid. I tried to replace the double slash with single or even by replacing the slash with some special characters in the database.

If I give the regex expression statically it works fine for me:

C# Code:

```
     bool isPhoneNumber = Regex.IsMatch(sColumnValue, @"^(\+44\s?7\d{3}|\(?07\d{3}\)?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$");
     if (isPhoneNumber == true)
       {
          //Do something...              
       }
      else
       {
          //Do something...
       }
```

But replaces when I get the Regex string stored in database.I have replaced "\" with special characters in database "@#@"  i.e.

```
    "^(@#@+44@#@s?7@#@d{3}|@#@(?07@#@d{3}@#@)?)@#@s?@#@d{3}@#@s?@#@d{3}$"
```

C# code:

```
    string sRegxE = Context.Fields.Where(s => s.Name == sColumnName).Select(s => s.ExpressionValue).FirstOrDefault();
    string sExpression= sRegxE.Replace(@"@#@", @"\");
    if (isPhoneNumber == true)
       {
          //Do something...              
       }
      else
       {
          //Do something...
       }
```

This doesn't work for me and I am getting the double slash instead of single slash with produces serious effect on Regex validation.

Can anybody help me to prevent the replacing of single backslash in C#, Cheers!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved it.

What I am doing here is instead of using "Regex.IsMatch()" directly,I created a Regex object and passing the dynamic value from the Sql server database i.e. ^(+44\s?7\d{3}|(?07\d{3})?)\s?\d{3}\s?\d{3}$, then check whether the input matches.

Code:

```
      string sRegxE =dbContext.GetFields.Where(s => s.Name == sColumnName).Select(s => s.ExpressionValue).FirstOrDefault();
      Regex RgxM = new Regex("" + sRegxE + "");
      Match isPhoneNumber = RgxM.Match(sColumnValue);
       if (isPhoneNumber.Success)
         {
           //Do somthing...
         }
```

Reference:
[Capture variable string in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6975949/capture-variable-string-in-a-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use .Replace() function like below :-

```
string temp = "^(@#@+44@#@s?7@#@d{3}|@#@(?07@#@d{3}@#@)?)@#@s?@#@d{3}@#@s?@#@d{3}$";

temp = temp.Replace("^(@#@+44@#@s?7@#@d{3}|@#@(?07@#@d{3}@#@)?)@#@s?@#@d{3}@#@s?@#@d{3}$", "\");
```

Or

```
temp = temp.Replace("^(@#@+44@#@s?7@#@d{3}|@#@(?07@#@d{3}@#@)?)@#@s?@#@d{3}@#@s?@#@d{3}$", "\\");
```

And can use it like :-

```
bool isPhoneNumber = Regex.IsMatch(sColumnValue, temp);
     if (isPhoneNumber == true)
       {
          //Do something...              
       }
      else
       {
          //Do something...
       }
```

**Edited:-**

You can also use **Regex.Unescape()**

Have a look on below link for more details :-

Many regular expressions contain escaped characters. Sometimes you want to unescape these characters to get their original representation.

https://www.dotnetperls.com/unescape

Comment: I am getting the expression from the database and using Replace() in my code but it dosen't  replace it. If I do it statically it will work for me.

Comment: you can use Regex.Unescape() for this.

Comment: Gives Exception when I try it: "parsing "^(\\+44\\s?7\\d{3}|\\(?07\\d{3}\\)?)\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d{3}$" - Unrecognized escape sequence \s."

Answer (score 0):

I tried the following code and it worked

```
string data = "+447712345678";
string pattern = @"^(@#@+44@#@s?7@#@d{3}|@#@(?07@#@d{3}@#@)?)@#@s?@#@d{3}@#@s?@#@d{3}$";
pattern = pattern.Replace(@"@#@", @"\");

if (Regex.IsMatch(data, pattern))
{
    //Do something...              
}
else
{
    //Do something...
}
```

Comment: @pavan What is the data you get from this line? Context.Fields.Where(s => s.Name == sColumnName).Select(s => s.ExpressionValue).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: "^(\\+44\\s?7\\d{3}|\(?07\\d{3}\)?)\\s?\\d{3}\\s?\\d‌​{3}$"" So I am using "@#@" to replace escape character.